# Why might this .vimrc.after file not be loading correctly?

Tags: vim

So I have a .vimrc.after setup as below using the [Janus plugin](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus) on Ubuntu 14.04.  The main trouble I'm having is that a line of text gets a line break (instead of wrapping) even when I don't press the enter key.  Any ideas as to why is this happening?   I've been experimenting a bit but haven't been able to come up with happening.

```
" When editing a text file, if you want word wrapping, but only want line breaks inserted when you explicitly press the Enter key:
:set wrap
:set linebreak
:set nolist  " list disables linebreak

" In addition, you will need to prevent Vim from automatically inserting line breaks in newly entered text. The easiest way to do this is:
:set textwidth=0
:set wrapmargin=0

" Configure for ctags
:set tags=./tags;  

" set clipboard=unnamedplus
set clipboard+=unnamed

" Use ack instead of grep
" set grepprg=ack

" Use Silver Searcher instead of grep
set grepprg=ag
```

Comment: It is possible you have a plugin or filetype setting interfering. What is the output of `:verbose set textwidth?` when you see this behavior? You can also try messing with the `'formatoptions'` setting.

Comment: Ok, interesting I get this:  textwidth=72 Last set from ~/.vim/janus/vim/core/before/plugin/filetypes.vim  .. This means the .vimrc.after is not loading properly - I wonder how to do that?  thanks @Ben

Comment: Wrong, your .vimrc loads fine. You installed a plugin that you did not understand and it has overwritten your settings from your .vimrc file. This is why "distributions" of Vim are often frowned upon. If you still want to use it, check the documentation for the distribution for how to override settings. In particular check the "customization" section.

Comment: Oh geeze I missed the ".after" part of your post. Check the output of `:scriptnames` to see if it is being sourced...if so you may have found a bug in your distribution. Remove it, or look into workarounds like autocmds.

Comment: thanks, so a solution to my problem is found in https://github.com/carlhuda/janus/issues/527 and all I have to is change a setting in .vimrc.before